# Как игнорировать копии при DropAction в QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Есть два QListWidget. Я копирую элементы из одного во второй. Второй должен содержать только уникальные элементы. Как мне это делать? Нужно как-то перехватывать элементы, которые я дроваю и проверять их и если они уже есть во втором QListWidget то игнорировать эти элементы. Не понимаю как это сделать. Есть идеи?
Вот как задан первый QListWidget

```
    user_panel_buttons = new QListWidget(nullptr);
    user_panel_buttons->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
    user_panel_buttons->setDragEnabled(true);
    user_panel_buttons->setAcceptDrops(true);
    user_panel_buttons->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::DropAction::CopyAction);
```